Nautilus not showing content properly
In my fresh install of ubuntu 23 when some application tries to open nautilus it shows bugged like i didnt have the correct font shows only squares
It hapened in two applications, postman and Bruno api client.
Someone can help me please?

Please define what you mean by Ubuntu 23.   Ubuntu's main products are year.month in format, eg. Ubuntu 23.10 for the 2023-October release, but there are also snap only products that are released on even years, eg. Ubuntu Core 22 is the snap only version of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but you mention 23 which is an odd year thus no snap products exist. What are you using?

I think it's a Gnome problem because I have the same problem with Fedora 40. It affects nautilusq Gnome-twiksq Fedy and the Software installer. Gnome-twiks  work after I reverted the version from Fedora 39.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
